# Column ambiguously defined en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to do `CASE WHEN` in Oracle, but I'm getting this error.

Something similar I do in SQL SERVER and it works.

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) as AMOUNT,Substr(con.DATES, 1,6 ) as DATES,
       CASE
          WHEN pro.cod_grup in ('54') and pro.cod_grup_2 in ('38')
            THEN 'WORKSHOPS'
            end as "ORIGIN"
   FROM AMOUNTS_B con inner join PRODUCTOS pro on con.product = pro.cod_product
        where DATES >= '20180101'
        group by FECHA, ORIGIN;
```

If the tables have aliases, why does the error occur?

Answer (score 2):

Your tables do not have a `ORIGIN` column, that is an alias you have defined in the `SELECT` clause and cannot use that alias in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Either repeat the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as AMOUNT,
       Substr(con.DATES, 1,6 ) as DATES,
       CASE
         WHEN pro.cod_grup in ('54') and pro.cod_grup_2 in ('38')
         THEN 'WORKSHOPS'
       end as "ORIGIN"
FROM   AMOUNTS_B con
       inner join PRODUCTOS pro
       on con.product = pro.cod_product
WHERE  Substr(con.DATES, 1,6 ) >= '20180101'
group by FECHA,
       CASE
         WHEN pro.cod_grup in ('54') and pro.cod_grup_2 in ('38')
         THEN 'WORKSHOPS'
       end;
```

or use an outer query, which can use the alias:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as AMOUNT,
       DATES,
       ORIGIN
FROM   (
  SELECT amount,
         fecha,
         Substr(con.DATES, 1,6 ) as DATES,
         CASE
           WHEN pro.cod_grup in ('54') and pro.cod_grup_2 in ('38')
           THEN 'WORKSHOPS'
         end as "ORIGIN"
  WHERE  Substr(con.DATES, 1, 6 ) >= '20180101'
  FROM   AMOUNTS_B con
         inner join PRODUCTOS pro
         on con.product = pro.cod_product
)
group by FECHA,
       ORIGIN;
```

*(Note: you may also need `DATES` in the `GROUP BY` clause.)*